# Why would serverless package need creds?

Tags: serverless-framework

According to the docs:

> you can package your project without deploying it to AWS

If this is the case, why would I get the below error?

```
AWS provider credentials not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a particular deployment bucket (instead of letting serverless create its own), then you may encounter this bug:

- ["serverless package" requires AWS access if deploymentBucket provider config is used #4040](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4040)

For now, you can hack the deployed server less code and comment out the check, then wait for the bug to be fixed.